# How to view complete JSF code before it gets rendered as HTML?

Tags: jsf

Is there a way how to view complete final JSP/xhtml page with JSF markup after all includes and template processing, including dynamically generated components just before it gets rendered as HTML page? Currently I am using JSF 2.1 with Richfaces 4.

Comment: What's the purpose? Logging (...) or developer's debugging? If the latter, have you considered `<ui:debug>`? It only doesn't run before it get rendered, as you so explicitly asked.

Comment: I did not express myself properly, ui:debug shows it as it looked like "before it is rendered". I did not mean before as in timeline. Thanks for this tip, it works nicely, the original purpose was debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get the resulting JSF component tree at the time the view is about to be rendered. Thus, it is possible to get it by using a [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) or [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html).

As all of the components on the page are children of [`UIViewRoot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html), you can traverse the tree by using its inherited [`UIComponentBase#getChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getChildren%28%29) method. The view root component can itself be obtained from the [`FacesContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) method [`FacesContext#getViewRoot()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29).

This is what internally is done by JSF when the context parameter `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `Development` and there is an error in your view: in this case the component tree is printed out. To enable it, add the following lines in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

All in all, the following method (and helpers) will do the job:

```
public String getComponentTree() {
    StringBuilder tree = new StringBuilder();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    List<UIComponent> componentTree = viewRoot.getChildren();
    appendComponentInfo(componentTree, tree, 0);
    return tree.toString();
}

private String getComponentInfo(UIComponent comp) {
    return (comp == null) ? "" : (comp.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + comp.getId());
}

private void appendComponentInfo(UIComponent comp, StringBuilder sb, int level) {
    if(comp == null) {
        return;
    }
    String indentation = (level == 0) ? "" : String.format("%"+ (4 * level) + "s", " ");
    sb.append(indentation + getComponentInfo(comp) + "\n");
    List<UIComponent> children = comp.getChildren();
    int size = children.size();
    level = (size > 0) ? (level + 1) : level;
    for(UIComponent c : children) {
        appendComponentInfo(c, sb, level);
    }
    level = (size > 0) ? (level - 1) : level;
}
```

The last thing to note, do not confuse JSF component tree and HTML generated output, as such confusion gave rise to the other answer.

Answer (score -2):

As JSF is a server side framework, you will not be able to view the prepared page without running it in the server. And dynamic contents also will be getting the values at run time only.

Comment: I want to see it on the server.

Comment: You confused JSF component tree, as OP requested in his question, with the ultimately generated HTML output.